# Mean differences using t-test

Tags: t-test

Is there a way I can use the t-test application if I only have the average of the two compare?

For example, I have an internal average which is 81% and an overall average number that is 82%, I was task to use these two numbers to see if there is a real difference in the two.

The overall average number that is 82% includes the internal data also.

Can someone help me please?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

No. We know 82% > 81% so you don't need to run a program to verify that. Without any measurement of your variability, t-test is not going to work.